# Health index / performance curve of a motor

Tags: motor, analysis, speed, torque, performance

I am collecting daily data of motors that consists of vibration in  three direction x,y,z , RPM, Temperature, kVAh, kWh, kVArh, average voltage (LL), average voltage (LN), average PF,  average current and frequency.

I am supposed to plot a health curve/Performance curve of this motor using the given parameters like this.(an example how the health curve should be.

[image: picvd2]

May I know what parameters are important to plot performance curve of motor? I know speed, temperature, vibration, kWh are to be considered. But i have no idea how to use these parameters to state a performance of motor.

[Here](http://simplemotor.com/calculations/) are some calculations to find out torque and plotting speed-torque curve, temperature- current, temperature- voltage.

How do i use all these plots, curves to depict a health index of motor?

Thank you.

Comment: The picture seems more an introduction commercial for the economists. Not based upon any EE knowledge. The next slide is probably BUY something.

Comment: That was just an example to plot. I would like to know how to use these parameters to make a performance curve of a motor.  [http://ijste.org/Article.php?manuscript=IJSTEV2I10158] Kindly check page 2 in this link. They have given a simple diagram which is exactly the same i posted.

Comment: I can't download from that link.

Comment: It seems that link is not working. I have replaced that image here since i cant add both due to reputation [https://www.scribd.com/document/339040255/Health-Index-Life-Expectancy-of-Generators]

Comment: (1) What is the motor driving? A constant or variable load? (2) Is this a work or educational exercise?

Comment: An internet search finds a number of papers using the general concepts and terms. |||| Surprising to me was that insulation paper strength / quality is a major factor. Not surprising but interesting

Answer (score 1):

The paper that you cited seems to provide the necessary information. The paper shows that the numerical results of various tests are normalized to 0-10 index values and weighted as described. The index values are then combined and plotted. You will need to search for the individual tests to find how the values are determined from the tests. You should read each of the papers cited in the paper. You should also search for subsequent papers that cit the paper that you cited. That may provide some additional clarification and indicate whether or not this "health index" has been well received.